# CSS3 Animation is not moving

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to move my block element to left with animation and even use animation shorthand property but its not moving.

Here's my HTML:

```
 <div id="game">
     <div id="block"></div>
     <div id="hole"></div>
     <div id="character"></div>
 </div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#game{
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: auto; 

}

#block{
    width: 50px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    left: 400px;
    animation: mblock 1s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: mblock 1s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: mblock 1s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mblock {
  0%{ left:400px };
  100%{ left:-50px };  
}

@-moz-keyframes mblock {
  0%{ left:400px };
  100%{ left:-50px };  
}


@keyframes mblock {
  0%{ left:400px };
  100%{ left:-50px };  
}

#hole{
    width: 50px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    left: 400px;
    top: -500px;
    animation: mblock 2s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: mblock 2s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: mblock 2s infinite linear;
    
}
```

Here's the JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/nwmLpdba/

Any idea what's causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the semi-colon would help.

```
@keyframes mblock {
  0%{ left:400px; } /* no need to add semicolon at the end of the block*/
  100%{ left:-50px; } /* no need to add semicolon at the end of the block */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@-webkit-keyframes mblock {

  100%{ left:-50px };  
}

@-moz-keyframes mblock {

  100%{ left:-50px };  
}


@keyframes mblock {

  100%{ left:-50px };  
}
```

please remove the 0%. Because 0% is already set in default class.